# Linux: why would something happen every 61 minutes?

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, cron, time

This could be extended to be; why would something happen regularly, but with an unusual interval?

Scheduled task runners such as cron would not do this without some fairly significant augmentation involved (e.g. running a script every minute which counts 61 times and executes).

I have a real world example of this happening currently, experiencing occasional communication link failures on a CentOS 7 server with a period of 61 minutes (not *every* 61 minutes, - but when there is a fault it will be some multiple of 61 minutes after the previous fault).

I'm investigating this bottom up with various tools; tcpdump, sar, analysing logs etc. but any thoughts on this from a top-down perspective would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are there any logs which show anything to do with this?

Comment: Are you sure the interval is not 60, followed by something that takes a minute...

Comment: It sounds like something is running for a minute, then scheduling a repetition for 60 minutes later. So the timer counts from the end of the previous instance rather than the beginning.

Comment: Possibly related: http://serverfault.com/questions/830163/mysql-communications-link-failure-periodically-every-61-minutes (or are you actually the same user?)